# Last row of the table without using any function or where clause

Tags: sql

In one of the technical interviews I was asked to find the last row of a Table without using where clause or any other defined sql functions. It was given that the table has integer ids as Primary key in the ascending order. I was only able to give an answer by `order by desc` of the table and later stuck on how to get the top row without where or any function. Can someone please help.

**EDIT** : There was no database constraint in the question. Assume any database which solves the query

Comment: The answer depends on the dbms. Put one of the tags back.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "last row" in a table, because tables represent *unordered* sets.  You can get the row with the largest `id`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff in that case i would need to use where or functions which is not allowed as per the question

Comment: I hope you are not working on all three databases so please add the one you are working on.

Comment: @Susang I request you to please read the EDIT that I made. There is no db constraint

Comment: There is no way to find the biggest value without using functions as MAX, TOP, ROWNUM or ordering and also being database agnostic. You could find the next auto-increment ID, the total amount of rows, etc by querying system tables but I think that's not the point. Maybe the question was given with no answer (it's a common interview technique), just to see the options you consider while thinking outloud.

Comment: That is a pretty stupid question in my opinion. There is no way to get that result without applying _some_ kind of "condition" like `fetch first 1 rows only` or whatever the non-standard equivalent for the DBMS in question is. And if the interviewer considered `fetch first n rows` a _function_ I would seriously doubt the interviewer's technical knowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming tableID is the surrogate key implemented as an autonumber/autoincrement

```
SELECT TOP 1 FROM tTable Order by tableID DESC
```

Comment: No functions or where clause is allowed as said in the question

Comment: How does the answer by @nicomp violate the rule against functions or `WHERE` clauses? @GordonLinoff is right. You *must* use `ORDER BY` or a table lacks any concept of first, last, or next row. It is probably a trick question.

Comment: I don't see a WHERE clause, so what function do you think I'm using?

Comment: @O.Jones interviewer was fine with ORDER BY but the moment I said TOP 1 he said no functions allowed..

Comment: @nicomp interviewer was fine with ORDER BY DESC but the moment I said TOP 1 he said no functions allowed.

Comment: This does not work in Oracle as it does not support the `TOP` keyword.

Comment: TOP 1 is not a function, it's a clause.

Comment: @ghostrider: there is no function that query

Comment: Specifically, `TOP` is not listed on [What are the SQL database functions?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/functions?view=sql-server-2017) and [TOP (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) includes "_Use this **clause** to specify the number of rows returned from a SELECT statement_"

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle 11g and below, this is not possible as it does not support the `TOP`/`LIMIT`/`FETCH` syntax and you would normally do:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT *
  FROM   table_name
  ORDER BY id DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

In PostgreSQL, Oracle 12 and SQL Server 2012 you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY id DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS           -- This line is optional in Oracle 12, PostgreSQL
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

In SQL Server, you can use `TOP`:

```
SELECT TOP 1
       *
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY id DESC
```

In MySQL, you can use `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: The second query is  actually standard ANSI SQL

Answer (score 2):

**TRY** `ROWCOUNT` for `SQL-SERVER` similarly you can use

`ROWNUM` or `FETCH FIRST` for `ORACLE` -- Do search for this, it quite easy to use

`LIMIT` for `MYSQL` -- Do search for this, it quite easy to use

```
SET ROWCOUNT 1
SELECT * FROM <table name> ORDER BY [id] DESC
```

Comment: This is `SQL-SERVER`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this. Relational databases are not required to keep their rows in any particular order... So, there's no way of knowing which row is physically stored last. You'll need to use the ORDER BY.

You might be able to improve performance with some appropriate indexes. This sort of thing should be pretty fast with an index.

Comment: In SQL Server the clustered index defines the physical order.